# How to update child object in a nested form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, controller, parent-child, nested-forms

I have a nested form Parent, which accepts attribute for Child.
In my controller#new, I do

```
  @parent = Parent.new
  @parent.childs.build
```

and the nested form works fine

For updating Parent and Child, in my controller#edit, I have

```
  @parent = Parent.find(params[:id])
  @parent.childs.build unless not @parent.childs.empty?
```

Now, if I go to edit page, only fields for parent will show up. My question is: 
How to I let Rails know that I want the form for Parent and Child, and not just for Parent?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `fields_for` helper - it will almost do everything for you.

```
<%= form_for @parent do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :children, @parent.children do |c| %>
    <%= c.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

- [The Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for)